# How to access node/content variables from hook_form_alter

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a cck field that I need to access in my hook_form_alter so I could set a certain field's default value with a dynamic value.

Apparently, node_load does not do the job for me.

```
   if ($form_id == 'some_form_id') {
    $node = node_load($item->nid); 
    $somevariable = $node->field_cck_foo[0]['value'] * 2;
    $form ['xxx']['xxx']['#default_value'] = $somevariable; 
}
```

How am I able to access the node items so I could use it inside hook_form_alter? Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Is this for Drupal 6 or Drupal 7? You've tagged it as both which isn't possible

Comment: Drupal 6. I thought the hook_form_alter still works the same on D7. Sorry for that. Tag edited now accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node_load() WILL get you all the CCK fields values, try doing a var_dump to see what's comming.

If node_load() isn't bringing the full node structure, try clearing the cache with this workaround http://drupal.org/node/158237#comment-4593950

Answer (score 0):

For D7:

```
$arg = arg();
if($arg[0] == 'node' && !empty($arg[1])) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
}
```